# errors in the script that generate latex template using perl

Tags: perl

I generated latex template using perl,and complied with MikTeX, its generating pdf. But I have some problems. I written script like this

```
  #!/usr/bin/env perl
     use strict;
     use warnings;
      use XML::Fast;
      use Template;

     my $xml = <<'XML';
              <student>
                 <number>24</number>
                 <education>bachelors</education>
                  <specialization>computers </specialization>
                   <address>
                    <house_number="128"/>
                     <street name="xxxx"/>
                    <proddutoor/>
                    </address>   
                </student>
                <student>
                 <number>23</number>
                  <education>ph.d.</education>
                   <specialization>physics </specialization>
                   <address>
                    <house_number="12"/>
                    <street name="xxxx"/>
                     <kadapa/>
                   </address>
                  </student>
                XML
           my $xml_hash = xml2hash $xml;

          my $template = Template->new();

           my $filename = 'output.tex';
    $template->process(\*DATA, $xml_hash, $filename)
      || die "Template process failed: ", $template->error(), "\n";

    system( "pdflatex $filename" );

       __DATA__
       \documentclass{article}

      \title{Roster}
       \author{pavani}

     \begin{document}
       \maketitle

    [% FOREACH st IN student %]
    Student [% st.number %] is a [% st.specialization %] [% st.degree %] student and          
     his address is[%address%][%house_number%][%street name%].
     [% END %]

     \end{document}
```

when I run it its generating pdf and printing like this

```
 student 24 is a computers student and his address is HASH(0x274b27c)
    student 23 is a computers student and his address is HASH(0x274b27c)
```

but I need to print address also how to get the address element content also like this

```
        student 24 is a computers student and his address is 
                       house_number="128";
                       street name="xxxx";
                        proddutoor.
         student 23 is a computers student and his address is 
                     house_number="12";
                       street name="xxxx";
                     kadapa.
```

what should I need to change to print like this in pdf.

2) I have one more question if I am giving input like this XML data its excuting what can I do if I have one file with data same as like this,for example more number of students data in one file. I tried to give file name to variable xml but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `[% st.address.house_number %]` and `[% st.address.street_name %]`. XML::Fast builds nested hashes that mirror the nested tags in your XML.

Comment: ok what should I need to do if my input is in a file. not like as I posted in The question. But the format is same in my file,but with more number of students in one file.how to do with file. I opened file assigned to $xml variable but its not working.

Comment: It looks like your code already handles multiple students. That's what the `[% FOREACH st IN student %]` does.

Comment: no that's not i am asking , if you see my at code I given only two students xml data as input, I have 150 number of students in one file so i am asking how can I assign that file as input to the code.here in this code i am assigning only two students information as input to the $xml variable, like that i opened file and assigned my file but it's not working. how to assign.

Comment: Open the file (`open my $xml_fh, '<', 'data.xml' or die $!`). Read the contents into a variable (`my $xml = do { local $/; <$xml_fh }`. Or look at the File::Slurp module.

Comment: After trying your code exactly I am getting error "undetermined operator "<>" in second line but I modified like this  (my $xml = do { local $/; <$xml_fh> }; but it doesn't print any output in pdf just generating pdf with author name. when I modified like this "<$xml_fh>" doesn't look like a variable. I am beginner to perl so plese can u tel me how to rectify this.